# Windows style selection для QtreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qss

Есть QtreeWidget, как для него сделать выделение как в windows-е?
(Хочется, чтобы при клике на элемент он выделялся полупрозрачным голубым цветом, бекграунд при этом должно быть видно.)
Выглядеть должно вот так:
[image: рандомный пример из гугла]

Comment: не совсем понятен ваш вопрос ибо , при выделении строки она окрашивает в виндувс стиль (если работаем в виндувс). Можете пожалуйста описать более конкретно (можно итерационально)

Comment: @timob256 Хочется чтобы на других системах было как в виндувсе. Т.е. при выделении был виден исходный бекграунд элемента.